# How can I create this table?

Tags: r

How do I fix this code? Trying to create the table at the bottom. Basic idea is showing employed / sum for each category. "private", "government", and "self" are all binary variables in the original file.

```
data1 = filter(data, data$employed != 0 & data$unemployed != 0)
table = data.frame(data1)

privateSum <- 0
privateEmployed <- 0
governmentSum <- 0
governmentEmployed <- 0
selfSum <- 0
selfEmployed <- 0

for(row in 1:nrow(table))
{
  if(row.table$private == 1)
  {
    privateSum <- privateSum + 1
    if(employed == 1)
    {
      privateEmployed <- privateEmployed + 1
    }
  }
  if(data$government == 1)
  {
    governmentSum <- governmentSum + 1
    if(employed == 1)
    {
      governmentEmployed <- governmentEmployed + 1
    }
  }
  if(data$self == 1)
  {
    selfSum <- selfSum + 1
    if(employed == 1)
    {
      selfEmployed <- selfEmployed + 1
    }
  }
}

tab <- matrix(c(privateEmployed / privateSum, governmentEmployed / governmentSum, selfEmployed / selfSum), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('Private','Government','Self')
rownames(tab) <- c('Proportion Retained')
tab <- as.table(tab)
```

Getting `Error in private : object 'private' not found` when private is a column name in the original file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your script assumes objects "data" and "table". What are they? It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: What do you mean `row.table$private` to do?

Comment: dont do this in a nested for loop, R is higly vectorized, you are missing the point. I assume employed and unemployed are numerical columns, whlie gov, self, private are bool and exclusive ( no row is goverment 1 and self 1 and private 1) ?

Answer (score 1):

### There are many ways to create such a table of proportions.

(Using nested for loops might be the worst one.)

#### Below I show some in "increasing level of R proficiency":

- Beginner: dplyr
- Advanced: using base R functions

### Please if someone knows more, provide additional examples how to:

- use data.table package
- use "Statsstyle" R:

  - reshape or stack
  - xtabs & proportions

.. because I don't know and want to learn..

```
## Test data 1:

data<-data.frame(
  employed = sample(c(3:100),100,TRUE),
  unemployed = sample(c(3:100),100,TRUE),
  government = sample(c(0,1),100,TRUE),
  private = sample(c(0,1),100,TRUE),
  self = sample(c(0,1),100,TRUE)
)


## Level 1: using dplyr
library(dplyr)
## level 1.0 group,summarise,mutate
data %>%
  group_by(government,private,self) %>%
  summarise(employed = sum(employed),
            unemployed = sum(unemployed)) %>%
  mutate(perc_employed= employed/(employed+unemployed))

## level 1.1 group, summarise
data %>%
  group_by(government,private,self) %>%
  summarise(prop_employed= sum(employed)/(sum(employed,unemployed)))

## level 2: using baseR:
### level 2.0 Using aggregate:
#### level 2.0.0 using factors:
data$government<-factor(data$government)
data$self<-factor(data$self)
data$private<-factor(data$private)
df<-aggregate(.~private+self+government,data,sum)
df$prop_emp<-df$employed / (df$employed+df$unemployed)
#### this is basically a good level to be on 
#### but in some cases, it could be smarter to calculate the proportion first and aggregate second
data$prop_employed<-data$employed / (data$employed+data$unemployed)
aggregate(prop_employed~private+self+government,data,\(x) sum(x) / NROW(x) )

#### level 2.1 using by and indexing
by(data[1:2],data[3:5],\(x) sum(x[1])/(sum(x[1],x[2])))


##### Bonus level:
## exclusive levels "government", "private", "self":

## Test data 2:

M <- matrix(0,100,3)
M[ cbind(1:100, sample(1:3, 100, rep=TRUE))] <- 1

data<-data.frame(
  employed = sample(c(3:100),100,TRUE),
  unemployed = sample(c(3:100),100,TRUE),
  government = M[,1],
  private = M[,2],
  self = M[,3]
)

library(tidyr)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(government:self,names_to = "sector") %>% 
  filter(value==1) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  group_by(sector) %>% 
  summarise(prop_emp=sum(employed)/sum(employed+unemployed))
```